# Pixel data from byte array Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to extract pixel data from a `byte` array. I am using this approach.

```
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(imagearray);
using (IRandomAccessStream randomAccessStream = memoryStream.AsRandomAccessStream())
{
    BitmapTransform transform = new BitmapTransform()
    {
         //these is original width and height 
         ScaledWidth = Convert.ToUInt32(width),
         ScaledHeight = Convert.ToUInt32(height)
    };
    decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(randomAccessStream);
    PixelDataProvider provider = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync(decoder.BitmapPixelFormat,decoder.BitmapAlphaMode, transform, ExifOrientationMode.IgnoreExifOrientation, ColorManagementMode.DoNotColorManage);
    byte[] pixels = provider.DetachPixelData();
 }
```

But every 4th index of `pixels` array is overwritten with a value of `255`, somthing like `{25,12,128,255(original value was 122),32,149,212,255(original value was 122),.....}` (i know the original value because original image was generated by application).

I have tried to do this the following way but same result.

```
var pixelStream = writableimage.PixelBuffer.AsStream();
var pixels2 = new byte[pixelStream.Length];
await pixelStream.ReadAsync(pixels2, 0, pixels2.Length);
```

These changes have no effect on appearance of the image but my application cannot tolerate such changes.

Comment: Arte you sure you're not misinterpreting the content of the array? this fourth byte is the Alpha channel...

Comment: To be honest, i am new in the world of image processing. Was the 4th byte useless? As it was overwritten and no way to retrieve it.

Comment: No, it's not uselesss, it represents the transparency of the pixel, a value of 255 means a solid pixel.

Comment: And what if i need to keep the original value?

Comment: I think you're mixing things, the imagearray comes from an image file? if it is, then the content of the array does not represent pixels, it's an image format and it has it's data compressed (each format uses different techniques) so you cannot compare one-to-one bytes from the source to the pixel data.

Comment: Also, if you stored your original image as a JPG (per example) it does not support transparency and the alpha channel will be removed, so the decoder will render the data with a solid alpha channel (255 value)

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity but  I am not comparing `pixels` with `imagearray`. Original image was generated by the application (no file used) and i know its `pixels` array contents. Then i saved and reloaded that image and compared its `pixels` array content with original one (that i knew in previous step), and the only byte changed is the Alpha Channel. I am using PNG as i thought it is somewhat alteration resistant.

Comment: Indeed PNG has the capability to preserve the image as-is. As a first try i would open the generated image with an editor like Photoshop and check if the image really has the alpha channel stored (the image must be semi transparent). If in the editor the image has this transparency, then try to pass "Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapAlphaMode.Straight" as the alpha mode to the decoder as it will preserve the alpha value.